# Python Two Spinboxs Equalling The Same Value

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm making a count down clock in python and it has spinboxs to set the value but when I have two they always equal the same as the other?
any help

```
    mins = ''
secs = ''

m = Spinbox(Window, from_ = 0, to = 60, textvariable = mins).pack()

s = Spinbox(Window, from_ = 0, to = 59, textvariable = secs).pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textvariable` option requires the use of a `StringVar` or `IntVar`:

```
minsVar = StringVar()
m = Spinbox(Window, ..., ,textvariable=minsVar)
```

Also, when you do `m=Spinbox(...).pack(...)`, `m` will always be `None` since that is what `.pack()` returns. You should separate the creation of the widget and the layout of the widget into two separate statements.